# @PostMapping working in Postman but not browser

Tags: java, spring-boot, post, postman, httprequest

I have a simple controller setup in my SpringBoot app that I have with no security. When I attempt to test my @PostMapping endpoint through the browser address bar, it throws a status of 405 (Request method 'GET' not supported); However, when I use Postman to send the POST request, it's fine. Why is that?

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    
    @PostMapping("/post")
    public void addNewUser() {
        User newUser = new User("testUser", "test@gmail.com", "password");
        userRepository.save(newUser);
        System.out.println(newUser);
    }
```

Comment: Your browser URL bar doesn't perform POST (or PUT) requests, only GET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**through browser access your endpoint the method  is get not post**

use postman to send request it's fine, it's prove the code is correct

Answer (score 0):

if you want to perform POST or PUT requests from the browser, use one of the below ways

- use html forms tags like [HTML FORMS](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp)
- use custom javascripts libraries like [jQuery Async POST Calls](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp)